# How can I process a query string in ProxyPass?

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to ProxyPass like this

ProxyPass /forum_feed https://example.com/rest/forum_feed?type=atom

The problem is that ProxyPass won't process query strings, so what rewrite rule can I write to trick it?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing  it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forum_feed
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/rest/forum_feed?type=atom [P]
```